# The interior of every finite set of R is empty with respect to the usual metric.

Tags: general-topology

I have a confusion as follows: if $(A,d)$ is a finite metric space, say $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, then for all $i\in [1,n]$, $\{a_i\}=B(a_i,r_i)$  where:
$$r_i=\text{min}\{d(a_i,a_j)\ |\ j\in [1,n], j\ne i  \}$$
hence $A$ is open, since it is the union of $n$ open sets, so in particular, if $A$ is a finite set of $\mathbb{R}$, one can view $(A,|\cdot|)$ as a metric space ( by restriction), an then $A$ is open, hence the interior of $A$ is $A$. But in the case  of the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ cannot contain an interval because it is infinite, thus the interior of A is $\emptyset$. So what is the cause that makes this contradiction?

Comment: The meaning of words "interior" and "open" depends on the surrounding metric space. You have discovered that "$A$ is an open subset of $Y$ and $Y \subset X$" does not imply "$A$ is an open subset of $X$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction:

- In the space $A$ (whose topology is the subspace topology it gets from the fact that $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$), the interior of $A$ is $A$ (the interior of *any* topological space is the whole space) and $A$ is an open set (*any* topological space is an open subset of itself).
- However, in the topological space $\Bbb R$, $A$ is *not* an open set, and its interior is empty.

Keep in mind that you are working with *two* distinct topological spaces here: $A$ and $\Bbb R$. If $B\subset A$ then the topological properties of $B$ as a subset of $A$ don't have to be the topological properties of $B$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$.